# RoR tutorial Hartl: Failing test in Chapter 9.1 - ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running through Michael Hartl's tutorial for the first time and having trouble getting the first test of chapter 9 ([Section 9.1.1](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#sec%3aedit_form) to pass. I'm getting a return citing issues with the ActiveRecord but I checked my schema and the reference code and I'm having a hard time finding what I have wrong. Someone previously had this problem due to a missing line in the users_controller, but I double-checked and that doesn't appear to be my issue, so any assistance would be much appreciated.

Here's the return I get:

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb -e "edit page"
Run options: include {:full_description=>/(?-mix:edit\ page)/}
FFF

Failures:

  1) User pages signup edit page
     Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path }
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'users'
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8:in `new'
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8:in `new'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:24:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User pages signup edit page
     Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path }
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'users'
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8:in `new'
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8:in `new'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:24:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) User pages signup edit page
     Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path }
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'users'
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8:in `new'
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8:in `new'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:24:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 5.45 seconds
3 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:64 # User pages signup edit page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:65 # User pages signup edit page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:66 # User pages signup edit page
```

And my code -- user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
  end

describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
end

describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
        it "should not create a user" do
            expect { click_button "Create my account"}.not_to change(User, :count)
        end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

it "should create a user" do
        expect do
          click_button "Create my account"
         end.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end

describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button "Create my account" }
        let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
        it { should have_link('Sign out') }
        end
     end
end

describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      sign_in user
      visit edit_user_path(user)
    end

    describe "page" do
      it { should have_selector('h1',    text: "Update your profile") }
      it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
      it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
    end

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Save changes" }

      it { should have_content('error') }
    end
  end
end
end
```

I confirmed that I do have a users table in my schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20120625023223) do

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_token"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
  add_index "users", ["remember_token"], :name => "index_users_on_remember_token"

end
```

And my users_controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

 def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
     redirect_to @user    
 else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

database.yml:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: Is that database table being created for the test? Is the database.yml settings correct for the test database?

Comment: No, the database table was already there from an earlier part of the tutorial -- I just saw the "could not find table 'users'" in the failures output and thought that might be relevant. I just added the database.yml settings to the end of my post -- I'm just learning this all for the first time so I'm not positive if there are issues there but I wouldn't assume so as I've not changed that file. Please let me know if there's anything else I should be including to make it easier to assist with. Thanks!

Comment: Dave: I just ran $ rake db:migrate and got the following: (in c:/sample_app)
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- bundler/setup
c:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_requi
re.rb:36:in `require'
c:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_requi
re.rb:36:in `require'

Comment: re.rb:36:in `require'
c:/sample_app/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
c:/sample_app/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
c:/sample_app/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
c:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `load'
c:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `raw_load_rakef
ile'

Comment: c:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007:in `block in load_
rakefile'
c:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_excep
tion_handling'
c:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006:in `load_rakefile'

c:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1991:in `run'
c:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'

Comment: I had a myriad of other problems going on that I had to remedy by completely uninstalling/reinstalling Ruby and the whole Rails package, but in the end running the migrations got the tests to pass -- thanks so much Dave!

Answer (score 6):

When you run tests it's the test database that's used and not development. So anytime you make schema changes make sure you also run `rake db:test:prepare` to sync those changes between development and test databases.

Comment: Thanks Dty -- I tried running that now and got a result starting with this: (in c:/sample_app)
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- bundler/setup
c:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_requi
re.rb:36:in `require'
c:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_requi
re.rb:36:in `require'
c:/sample_app/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'

Comment: Sorry, haven't done rails development in windows. But try running everything with `bundler exec`. So for example, `bundler exec rake ...`. If that doesn't work I'd try updating bundler.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since the OP, but I just ran into the same problem. Environment Win7 64-bit with RailsInstaller.

Running `rake db:test:prepared` didn't fix it.

Running `rake db:reset` followed by `rake db:test:prepare` finally did.

Note you must stop the server before the reset.